# Freenas, rsyncd max log size

Tags: logging, freebsd, bsd

I've been experiencing some issues with Rsync, and want to read the errors in the log file, however, somewhere it caps at 32kb, which means about 4 minutes, and I really need to be able to look at least 24hours back.

Eg:

```
32 -rw-------  1 root  wheel   32768 Nov 16 08:46 daemon.log
32 -rw-------  1 root  wheel   32768 Nov 15 13:53 ftp.log
32 -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   32768 Nov 16 08:26 lastlog
 4 drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel     512 Oct 26 22:17 proftpd
 0 -rw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel       0 Sep 15 13:21 rsync_client.log
 0 -rw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel       0 Sep 15 13:21 rsync_local.log
32 -rw-------  1 root  wheel   32768 Nov 16 08:49 rsyncd.log
```

How do I increase the max size?

Comment: Could you please show the /etc/newsyslog.conf ?

Comment: @AndriyRadyk there is no such file.

Comment: What version of Freenas do you use?

Comment: @AndriyRadyk version 7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change nentries value in **/conf/config.xml** :

```
    <syslogd>
            <nentries>50</nentries>
            <!--
            <reverse/>
            <resolve/>
            <remote>
                    <enable/>
                    <ipaddr>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</ipaddr>
                    <daemon/>
                    <ftp/>
                    <rsyncd/>
                    <smartd/>
                    <sshd/>
                    <system/>
            </remote>
            -->
    </syslogd>
```